# google apps script disappeared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I was just rechecking all of my websites as I updated to PHP7 now I realised that my Google-script wasn't working properly. Now that I logged in to the script.google page I noticed they are all gone - no trace. When I open the previously working link it says I'm not allowed to open the script. Putting the Script-ID in the explorer to open the edit page it says there is no such script.
corresponding link: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxnewLUtjWIlEITiX5RYRi-ZtJuI87nQ1G8t1rVnuGfUntsZXu9/exec?year=2017

Comment: We can't see that link as it'll only be visible for you.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that how do I make it visible for you? [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxnewLUtjWIlEITiX5RYRi-ZtJuI87nQ1G8t1rVnuGfUntsZXu9/exec?year=2017)

Comment: The link contains `/exec?year=2017` at the end, so this tells me that opening it would be executing the script, not opening it. Are you the owner of the scripts or did someone share them with you previously? This would be easily explainable by the fact that whoever made the scripts either deleted them, removed you from the shared list or his/her account was suspended/deleted

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, I am the owner of the script. When I open my scripts.google it is blank - I had about 4 scripts running - all I got left is this execution-link that I embedded to my webside.

Comment: likely this https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5831